# CakePhp isUniquer Apparently Wrong

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to use this validation set for username field in my `User` model:

```
public $validate = [
        'password'  => [
            'rule-1'=>array(
                'rule'       => array('minLength','6'),'message'=> 'At least 6 letters',
                'allowEmpty' => true),

            'rule-3'=>array(
                'rule'=> '/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z\d@!#$%_-]{7,}$/', 
                'message'=>'Wrong password')
        ],
        'username' => [
            'unique' => array(
                'rule'    => ['isUnique',['username'],false],
                'required' => 'create',        
                'message' => 'Username present!'
            )
        ]
    ];
```

But whenever I try to add a new record to my `User` model the validation fails and it says the `username` is already present, while it is not.

Answer (score 0):

My fault.
I had a `beforeFind()` function in `AppModel.php` which changed the query!
Changing that `beforeFind()` solve the problem.